# Customising the new CKEditor5 in Craft 3

Tags: wysiwyg, ckeditor5

How do you configure the new CKEditor editor to e.g. add images? Do you create a config/CKeditor folder with a .json file and install the @ckeditor/ckeditor5-image package?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. You can see the entire code [here](https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/blob/master/src/Field.php#L128)

```
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.getElementById('{$nsId}'))
    .then(function(editor) {
        $(editor.element).closest('form').on('submit', function() {
        editor.updateEditorElement();
    });
})
```

This is the javascript that triggers the editor, as you can see, there are no [config settings](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html) provided yet. I searched in the entire plugin but I could not find any other Javascript functions that are triggert so unless they provided a really nasty method to include them in the [original editor js file](https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/dist/ckeditor.js) you can't change them yet.

The only "configurations" are [Html Purifier](https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor#html-purifier-configs)

**Edit**

However - you could create a feature request or you could implement your own code to provide settings. You only need to change a few lines - it's totally trivial

Comment: Thanks Robin, looks like the ckeditor5-image plugin hasn't been included - maybe because the Craft plugin is still in β?

Comment: I don't know, like I said you are free to create a feature request or a pull request or just include the plugin by yourself